# Plotting data in R: Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

Trying to plot some data in R - I am a basic user and teaching myself. However, whenever I try to plot, it fails, and I am not sure why.

```
> View(Pokemon_BST)
> Pokemon_BST <- read.csv("~/Documents/Pokemon/Pokemon_BST.csv")
>   View(Pokemon_BST)
> plot("Type_ID", "Gender_ID")

Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

This is my code, but I thought it might be an issue with my .csv file? I have attributed numbers to the "Type_ID" and "Gender_ID" columns. Type_ID has values between 1-20; Gender_ID has 1 for male, 2 for female, and 3 for both. I should state that both ID columns are just made of numeric values. Nothing more.

I then tried using barplot function. This error occurred:

```
> barplot("Gender_ID", "Type_ID")

Error in width/2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(width) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

There are no missing values, no characters within these columns, nothing that SHOULD cause an error according to my basic knowledge. I am just not sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems as you are giving the `plot` function the wrong inputs.
For the x and y axis `plot` expects numeric values and you are only providing a single string. The function does not know that the `"Type_ID"` and `"Gender_ID"` come from the `Pokemon_BST` data frame.

To reach your data you must tell `R` where the object comes from. You do this by opening square brackets behind the object you want to access and write the names of the objects to be accessed into it.

```r
View(Pokemon_BST)
Pokemon_BST <- read.csv("~/Documents/Pokemon/Pokemon_BST.csv")
# Refer to the object 
plot(Pokemon_BST["Type_ID"], Pokemon_BST["Gender_ID"])

# Sould also work now 
barplot(Pokemon_BST["Gender_ID"], Pokemon_BST["Type_ID"])
```

See also [here](https://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html) for a introduction on subsetting in `R`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have done the trick... The plot function comes up with this error:

```Error in stripchart.default(x1, ...) : invalid plotting method```

The barplot function comes with this error:

```Error in barplot.default(Pokemon_BST["Gender_ID"], Pokemon_BST["Type_ID"]) : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(width) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA```

Comment: Pokemon_BST["Gender_ID"] is a list. We want a vector for the plot function. A vector would be Pokemon_BST[,"Gender_ID"]
The code should be:
```plot(Pokemon_BST[,"Type_ID"], Pokemon_BST[,"Gender_ID"])```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you're passing the values to the plot function. In your code above, "Gender_ID" is just some string and the plot function doesn't know what to do with that. One way to plot your values is to pass the vectors Pokemon_BST$Gender_ID and Pokemon_BST$Type_ID to the function.

Here's a sample dataframe with the plot you were intending.

```
Pokemon_BST <- data.frame(
  Type_ID = sample(1:20, 10, replace = TRUE),
  Gender_ID = sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE))

plot(Pokemon_BST$Gender_ID, Pokemon_BST$Type_ID)
```